# Creating SFDX Project from existing Source

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, scratch-org

we have a pretty big org and decided to implement sfdx now. We want to split up the org in different sfdx projects. The first module we want to convert to sfdx is a visualforce page.
I followed the following guide:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/07/migrating-existing-projects-salesforce-dx.html

First of all in the unmanaged package there are huge dependencies covering almost 50% of the org's data. I followed the guide but once I run force:source:push it takes around 1 hour and then returns over 8000 errors.

I have no clue how to resolve those errors. Is there any other way to split up different modules out of an existing org? All information I found on this are only small test cases with 2 classes or so.

Comment: The error list is really verbose due to dependency chains causing large number of failures off a single issue. You'll need to dig through these manually, and peel some of the source out into their own projects. This is the exact issue which caused me to drop sfdx, I need to be delivering, and not working on a broken source. It seems really effective for small or org-independent code, but once you use a huge source file, the dream is shattered. Even the org shape pilot doesn't seem to be designed to resolve this.

Comment: Redesigning your code to work off of different dependencies, (Such as a fieldset, or a custom setting instead of a list of field names), could help you skip some of the dependency chaining.

Comment: Had similar issues with DX. After 1 week of work, gave it up until Salesforce fix  some basic issues. It looks like force:source:push is just a deployment like ant / eclipse.